# Create 2d ripple effect with sprite kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

How can i create a 2D ripple effect on water with **sprite kit**.

Like i have a scene which include **2D** still **water** and when tapped on that, small circles appears  scale and disappear say **5-6** circles scaling parallel giving the feeling of ripples Not actualy doing anything to water just creating images on it.

I was wondering what could be the best way to sole this problem. How can i achieve something like that. Any ideas?

Comment: Just add circles and scale them up while fading out, it should do a trick. Spawning circles at the same point with some time between them should do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In node in which you wish to create ripple just do something like this

```
    NSTimeInterval singleRippleDuration = 1.0f;
    CGFloat ripleEndScale = 3.0f;
    NSTimeInterval timeBetweenRipples = 0.3f;
    NSUInteger numberOfRipples = 5;
    SKAction* scaleUpAction = [SKAction scaleTo:ripleEndScale duration:singleRippleDuration];
    SKAction* fadeOutAction = [SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:singleRippleDuration];

    SKAction* rippleAction = [SKAction group:@[scaleUpAction,fadeOutAction]];

    SKAction* createRipple = [SKAction runBlock:^{
        //Create your ripple node somehow (SKShapeNode or SKSprite will do)
        //set it to a desired position
        [rippleNode setPosition:desiredPosition];
        //Set scale to 0 so it scales from point
        [rippleNode setScale:0.0f];
        [rippleNode runAction:createRipple];
        [self addChild:rippleNode];
    }];

    SKAction* wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:timeBetweenRipples];

    [self runAction:[SKAction repeatAction:[SKAction sequence:@[createRipple,wait]] count:numberOfRipples]];
```

Comment: Hi, your sample code looks nice but i can't make it works. I used this code to create a circle (not filled) to draw the ripple effect.`+(SKShapeNode *) dibujarCircunferencia:(NSInteger) radio
{
 CGRect box = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, radio, radio);
 CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
 CGPathAddEllipseInRect(path, NULL, box);
 
 SKShapeNode *circle = [SKShapeNode node];
 circle.path = path;
 CGPathRelease(path);
 circle.alpha = 0.5f;
 circle.lineWidth = 1.0f;
 circle.strokeColor = [SKColor orangeColor];
 
 return circle;
}`

Comment: And here is the gcd block.`runBlock:^{
  //Create your ripple node somehow (SKShapeNode or SKSprite will do)
  SKShapeNode *rippleNode;
  SKSpriteNode *rn;
  rippleNode = [punto dibujarCircunferencia:150];
  //set it to a desired position
  rippleNode.position = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
  //Set scale to 0 so it scales from point
  rippleNode.scale =0.0f;
  rippleNode.lineWidth = 0.5f;
  rn = rippleNode;
  rn.zPosition = 1.0f;
  
  [rippleNode runAction:createRipple];
  [self.player addChild:rn];
 }];` I don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: For start i am unsure what are you doing at all :)
1) check if your rippleNode gets instanced properly.
2) there is no need for SKSpriteNode* rn, simply use rippleNode everywhere

Comment: Please, post the final code, code above gives warnings as variables are not being used...

Comment: what is `self` and what is `rippleNode`? Could you provide a full workable example?

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in the "CreateRipple" method, it runs itself in the codeblock rather than "rippleAction" like it should, the corrected method is:

```
SKAction* createRipple = [SKAction runBlock:^{
    //Create your ripple node somehow (SKShapeNode or SKSprite will do)
    //set it to a desired position
    [rippleNode setPosition:desiredPosition];
    //Set scale to 0 so it scales from point
    [rippleNode setScale:0.0f];
    [rippleNode runAction:rippleAction];
    [self addChild:rippleNode];
}];
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: again - what is `self` and what is `rippleNode`?

Comment: I was just correcting the answer above, I didn't have the exp to comment it so just whacked it in another answer (sorry if that's the wrong way to do it), refer to above for the rest of the info

Comment: The code would be inside any method on a view controller, a touch action for example. The node itself could just simply be a circle / oval sprite, as it grows bigger and fades like a ripple

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete very simple example of @Dobroćudni Tapir code. If developing for iOS you can try in touchesBegan instead of mouseDown.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        /* Called when a mouse click occurs */
        let location = theEvent.locationInNode(self)
        let singleRippleDuration = 1.0
        let ripleEndScale = CGFloat(3.0)
        let timeBetweenRipples = 0.3
        let numberOfRipples = 3
        let scaleUpAction = SKAction.scaleTo(ripleEndScale, duration: singleRippleDuration)
        let fadeOutAction = SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(singleRippleDuration)
        let rippleAction = SKAction.group([scaleUpAction, fadeOutAction])

        let createRipple = SKAction.runBlock({
            let rippleNode = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 200)
            rippleNode.position = location
            rippleNode.setScale(0)
            rippleNode.runAction(rippleAction)
            self.addChild(rippleNode)
        })

        let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(timeBetweenRipples)
        runAction(SKAction.repeatAction(SKAction.sequence([createRipple, wait]), count: numberOfRipples))
    }
}
```